# MVP без presenter

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp, антипаттерн

У меня есть простая программа:

- Во view есть EditText, куда пользователь вводит поисковый запрос;
- model по этому запросу загружает список ответов с сервера.

Так вот, presenter получается абсолютно пустым: view говорит ему - сделай запрос! - Он хорошо!, передаю запрос в model.Model возвращает ему результат, presenter вызывает метод "показать Результат" у view. И собственно все. С тем же успехом view может напрямую общаться с model. И вроде бы ни читабельность текста, ни вопросы тестирования приложения, ни аспект разделения логики и view, ни как не ухудшаются.

Имеет ли место быть такая вариация MVP без P, или все же лучше делать как принято?

Comment: Без презентера это не MVP

Comment: Михаил, описанный вариант похож на паттерн DocumentView и именно к этому шаблону и подталкивает сама система андроид. Но ведет это к нагромождению вью. И вроде как такой подход не пользуется нынче популярностью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело ещё и в том, что при MVP модель не зависит от активити и её жизненного цикла, она просто передаёт данные в презентер, презентер создаётся один раз и не пересоздаётся, а просто берёт view из новой активности (при правильной реализации паттерна MVP).

При MVC возможна, например, такая ситуация, что AsyncTask закончит загрузку данных и "захочет" передать их в активность, но  активность может быть уничтожена, AsyncTask будет хранить ссылку на старую активити. Из-за этого произойдёт ошибка.

При MVP AsyncTask передаёт данные в презентер, который не пересоздаётся, затем презентер просто передаёт данные в новую активность и командует ей показать их.

Даже если у вас Model в MVP не выполняет сложных операций, ценность презентера в том, что активити перестаёт быть God-object, который управляет сложными асинхронными операциями, но при этом может быть уничтожена и пересоздана. Активити не управляет получением данных (любых, даже элементарных), а просто получает готовые данные. Это безопасно и логично.

С другой стороны, вы не уточнили, что за операции выполняются у вас в Model. Получение ли данных из сети/БД или же совсем простые, статические данные.
Во втором случае имеет смысл даже отказаться от MVP и использовать классический MVC, паттерны нужно выбирать для конкретных задач.

Comment: Model берет данные из сети. Подскажите тогда, "правильная реализация MVP", вы имеете ввиду что presenter одиночка, у которого есть метод инициализацияView? Мне вот как раз не очень нравится что model создается в presentore, мне тяжело это тестировать, да и реализацию принципов DI в таком случае мне сложно понять.

Comment: @Михаил ну вообще да, типо того. Презентер внедряют даггером, и view привязывают и отвязывают тоже. Посмотрите как здесь, если не видели:
https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/473-mvp-na-primere-jekrana-s-pin-kodom.html
Я сам если честно не очень разбираюсь пока в  этом, в моём приложении я создаю объект класс модели в презентере, а сам MVP реализую с помощью библиотеки Moxy